# MobileConnect Rest Api Credentials

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, mobileconnect, sms

I have got access to **SalesForce Marketing Cloud** (exacttarget.com)  and there I see MobileConnect activated with several **SMS** Outbounds that works well. As I understood, I can send SMS using next link:

```
https://www.exacttargetapis.com/sms/v1/messageContact/{{ API Key }}/send
```

But I need Authorization in header. I tried to get token using next URL:

```
https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken
```

But I need **clientId** and **clientSecret**.

***Question:*** I think the Rest API is already created and somewhere these credentials exist, but I can't find them in Marketing Cloud. Where I can find them? There to enter? What to search?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a ClientID and ClientSecret in the [App Center](https://appcenter-auth.s1.marketingcloudapps.com/). You'll need to create an account, then set up a new "App" of type "API Integration". The last page of the New App Wizard will provide you with ClientID and ClientSecret. With these details you can [get a session token from the Auth endpoint](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-getting-started.meta/mc-getting-started/requestToken.htm) to make calls against the API.

See an [overview](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/index-api.htm) of using Marketing Cloud REST APIs for further details.

Comment: Ou, thanks. Now I'm in AppCenter and on the 2nd step (Integrate) I see a button "Link to Account". I guess, it offers me to link account from AppCenter and account from Marketing Cloud. I can confirm and link, but what if another account from AppCenter is already linked? Can two account from AppCenter be linked to same account from Marketing Cloud? Can the have separate APIs? Look strange for me...

Comment: You can create as many different "Apps" to as many different SFMC accounts as you like. Each SFMC Account can have many Apps (ClientID and ClientSecret). I work with a large number of clients and have a mountain of these things created over the years. Each App only gives access to a single Business Unit in your account, so make sure that you select the correct Business Unit, if you have a multi-BU setup.